# Aligning 4 divs with dynamic height with CSS

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have 4 divs which I want to pisition in a clean as possible way.
They all contain lists that can get longer at different rates.
Most likely the 2th div will be the longest.

What I have now is floated #1,3,4 to the left and #2 to the right, this works fine if #2 is long enough (scenario 1) but if #2 is shorter than #1 than #4 leaves a big space between #1 & #4 (scenario 2)
In the end once #2 outgrows the rest it should look like scenario 3

[Image illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olVV7.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why not just make 2 containers and float those left then just put 2 lists in each?

Comment: i forgot to add I want container #2 to always be on the right side. & if you put 1&3 and 2&4 together it wouldn't look nice if 2 is bigger then 1&3 together.

Comment: Can you supply a live version of what you have done so far on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Scenario 1 in my illustration is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/MmXne/8/

Comment: edited the illustration so it now shows scenario 1 correctly

Comment: @Karel: that seems to imply you need to determine what order and/or containers you out put the lists in based on the length of the lists... in order to do that you would need to bring some scripting into the equation....

Comment: @prodigitalson: I guess that's what I'll do then, until someone finds a way to do it with css only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your illustration here is what I would do:

Create two divs stacked next to each other that are the same height, e.g.

```
<div class="1"></div><div class="2">
<div class="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="3"></div><div class="4">
```

Then set the divs the same min-height, but if you have a border around them it makes it a bit tricky like you mentioned so the way around that is to create a background image that will wrap around both divs:

```
<div class="wrapperbg"><div class="1"></div><div class="2"></div>
<div class="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="wrapperbg"><div class="3"></div><div class="4"></div>
```

That way you can set .wrapperbg to the same background image and it will stretch to accomodate the size of both divs.  make sure you set overflow to hidden (overflow:hidden;) on .wrapperbg because your divs are probably going to be floated.

Answer (score 0):

I have run across this problem before with CSS, but sadly I can't remember how I (if? lol..) fixed it. For some reason the third div gets hung up on the bottom of the second.

Regardless, I wrote a little js script that works, despite being pretty hack:

```
height = document.getElementById("col2").offsetHeight;
if (height <= 60) {
    var col4 = document.getElementById("col4");
    var margOrig = parseInt(col4.getStyle('margin-top'));
    height = height + margOrig;
    col4.style.marginTop = "-" + height + "px";
}
```

The size of 60 is set here just for the contrived example on JSfiddle. This obviously isn't complete, its more of a sketch. I don't know how consistently the columns are your site are going to be filled, etc etc. Hopefully you can find a CSS solution.

Heres the fiddle if you want - http://jsfiddle.net/MmXne/11/ 
Sorry this isn't exactly what you were looking for. I spent about an hour messing with the CSS and no luck:-/

Edit2: An even better way would be to subtract the height of col2 from col1. Then if it is `>= 0`, run the script. Once the second column becomes longer than the first, the floating gets messed up anyway, which is an entirely new problem.